# Stripe Connect - Provide Login Link for Standard Accounts

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm following these docs to setup `Stripe Connect` with `Standard` accounts in `Node.js`.

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts

I've successfully created the account and collected all the required info as the docs suggest, using the onboarding flow provided by Stripe.

I'd like to have a button that the users can use to quickly access their Stirpe dashboard from my application (the actual dashboard, not the onboarding flow).

I've found these docs: https://stripe.com/docs/api/account/create_login_link?lang=go however, this is meant to work only for `Express` accounts. What URL can redirect my users to in order to allow them access to their Stripe dashboard for Standard accounts once these accounts have been succesfully configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assemble a link to a specific Standard account dashboard like this:

```
https://dashboard.stripe.com/b/<accountID>
```

Where `<accountID>` is the account ID of the Stripe account you want to link to.  Typically those account IDs will start with `acct_`, so the link will end up looking something like this:

```
https://dashboard.stripe.com/b/acct_example
```

You can also add a `destination` query parameter to direct them to a specific page in the Dashboard.  Take this link, for example:

```
https://dashboard.stripe.com/b/acct_example?destination=/customers
```

That link would take you to the Customers list for the specified account.